# Truncate a string with an ellipsis, making sure not to break any HTML entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, xhtml, truncate

I have a database of items with XHTML content and I want to display the items with the HTML stripped off (done) and then truncate each item to a maximum length of 100 characters. If the string exceeds 100 characters, I cut it off and insert `&hellip;` (an ellipsis) at the end.

The problem is that my program doesn't understand HTML entities that are *already* in the string. E.g. if the string is `something &amp; something`, my function may truncate it as `something &am...` resulting in *invalid XHTML*.

What is the best way to go about this problem in ASP.NET/C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) to convert html entities to normal string, then truncate this string and finally encode the result:

```
var decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(theEncodedString);
decoded = Truncate(decoded);
var result = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(decoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to match either an HTML entity or a single character, and repeat up to the length that you want. Something like:

```
^(&\w+;|.){,100}
```